# In SQL Server can you Dynamic Mask some data in one column based on the value in another column?

Tags: sql-server

I'm just learning about SQL Server's Dynamic Data Masking.  I want to mask data in one column if the customer group = a specific number but not mask the rest.  Is that possible?  I thought of doing it with two temp-tables then doing a union but because the mask is on one temp-table it masks the column from both temp-tables.  Any way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think dynamic data masking supports conditional masking, can you reach your goal using row level security https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/granting-row-level-permissions-in-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN ?

Comment: I didn't think so either and we can't use row level security for reasons beyond my pay grade.  ;)  I found a way to do it and posted my solution.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Found a way that works!  I created a temp-table #tmp1 with a mask on column ABC and another temp-table #tmp2 exactly the same but without a mask.

```
select * into #tmp1 where customer group = 123
select * into #tmp2 where customer group <> 123

select *
  into #masked 
  from #tmp1

select * 
  into #notmasked
  from #tmp2

select * from #tmp1
union all
select * from #tmp2
```

Now the data from #tmp1 is masked and the data from #tmp2 is not masked but it is all together in one select. Crazy way to do it but it works.  :)